# Subscript out of range in Excel VBA workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

[IMAGE OF CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJCgw.png)

```
Dim mappingExportFile As Workbook



Workbooks.Open "/Users/avanlandingham/Documents/MappingExport_Files_2022_8_24.xlsx"
   
For Each Workbook In Workbooks
    Debug.Print Workbook.Name
Next
   
**Set mappingExportFile = Workbooks("/Users/avanlandingham/Documents/MappingExport_Files_2022_8_24.xlsx")**
```

I am receiving a subscript out of range error on the highlighted line. I am able to open the workbook using Workbooks.Open, then I am able to print the name of the workbook in the immediate window, but I am not able to assign the workbook to a Workbook object using the exact same name.

Comment: You should assign the Workbook to an object as you open it: `Set <object> = Workbooks.Open(<path & filename>)`

Comment: When accessing a workbook via the `WorkBooks` collection you only pass in the workbook name, not the full path.  Getting a reference to it at the same time you open it would be the preferred method here though, as noted by @cybernetic.nomad